# How can I specify an editor to use for the pip config edit --editor command that contains spaces in the file path?

Tags: python, pip

`pip config edit --editor notepad` works.

`pip config edit --editor "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"` does not work.

How can I assign NPP as the editor without adding it to path?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Set this environment var:

`VISUAL`

to

`"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"`

Then you don't need to use `--editor` at all unless you want to.

After the change, restart your shell and just say `pip config edit`.